# How to get Object from CallableStatement.(Invalid column index)

Tags: java, plsql

I need to execute procedure PL sql in java.

My PL/SQL.

```sql
TYPE REF_CURSOR IS REF CURSOR;
PROCEDURE GET_REPORT( P_account_number_param    IN VARCHAR2,
                      P_cycle_cut_param         IN VARCHAR2,
                      P_from_date_param         IN VARCHAR2,
                      P_to_date_param           IN VARCHAR2,
                      P_last_requested_by_param IN VARCHAR2,
                      P_worker_id_param         IN VARCHAR2,
                      P_requeset_type_param     IN VARCHAR2,
                      P_INQUIRY                 OUT REF_CURSOR,
                      P_RESULT                  out varchar2);
```

When I execute throws error `rs = (ResultSet) cstmt.getObject(8);` Line
Description Error: Invalid Column Index.
Vendor code:17003

I tried many ways to get index 1 ,2 or 8  but not working.

Java

```java
CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall(sql);
int paramIdx = 1;
// pass IN parameter
if (params != null)
    for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        cstmt.setString(paramIdx++, params[i]);
    }
// register result
cstmt.registerOutParameter(paramIdx++, OracleTypes.CURSOR);// index = 8
cstmt.registerOutParameter(paramIdx++, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
cstmt.execute();
rs = (ResultSet) cstmt.getObject(8);
ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
int columns = md.getColumnCount();
results = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
```

This is my PL/sql :

```sql
PROCEDURE GET__REPORT(P_account_number_param    IN VARCHAR2,
                                          P_cycle_cut_param         IN VARCHAR2,
                                          P_from_date_param         IN VARCHAR2,
                                          P_to_date_param           IN VARCHAR2,
                                          P_last_requested_by_param IN VARCHAR2,
                                          P_worker_id_param         IN VARCHAR2,
                                          P_requeset_type_param     IN VARCHAR2,
                                          P_INQUIRY                 OUT REF_CURSOR,
                                          P_RESULT                  out varchar2) is
SQL_STRING VARCHAR2(5000);
  BEGIN
BEGIN
 --OPEN P_INQUIRY FOR
 SQL_STRING := 'select a.account_number , a.cycle_cut , a.last_requested_by, a.last_requested_date , 
                CASE a.app_status 
                  WHEN ''I'' THEN ''Initial failed'' 
                  WHEN ''G'' THEN ''Generate failed''  
                  WHEN ''C'' THEN ''Check-In failed'' 
                  WHEN ''F'' THEN ''Send fax failed'' 
                  WHEN ''S'' THEN ''Successful'' 
                  ELSE a.app_status
                END as app_status
                , c.email 
                ,
                CASE c.email_status 
                  WHEN ''P'' THEN ''Wait'' 
                  WHEN ''Y'' THEN ''Success''
                  ELSE c.email_status 
                END as email_status 
                , d.fax_no 
                , 
                CASE d.fax_status 
                  WHEN ''P'' THEN ''Wait'' 
                  WHEN ''Y'' THEN ''Success''
                  WHEN ''D'' THEN ''Fax failed''
                  WHEN ''F'' THEN ''Gen Billing failed'' 
                  WHEN ''N'' THEN ''Billing not found'' 
                  WHEN ''U'' THEN ''CD not available'' 
                  ELSE d.fax_status 
                END as fax_status   
                from 
                ecm_billing_tax a LEFT JOIN ecm_billing_req b 
                ON a.billing_tax_id = b.billing_tax_id
                LEFT JOIN ecm_billing_tax_email c
                ON b.billing_tax_email_id = c.billing_tax_email_id
                LEFT JOIN ecm_billing_tax_fax d
                ON b.billing_tax_fax_id = d.billing_tax_fax_id
              Where a.account_number is not null ';


      IF P_account_number_param IS NOT NULL  THEN
            SQL_STRING := SQL_STRING ||' and a.account_number = ''' ||P_account_number_param || '''';
         END IF;
      IF P_cycle_cut_param IS NOT NULL  THEN
            SQL_STRING := SQL_STRING ||' and a.cycle_cut = to_date(''' ||P_cycle_cut_param || ''',''DD/MM/YYYY'') ';
         END IF;
      IF P_from_date_param IS NOT NULL  THEN
            SQL_STRING := SQL_STRING ||' and trunc(a.last_requested_date) >= to_date(''' ||P_from_date_param || ''',''DD/MM/YYYY'') ';
         END IF;
      IF P_to_date_param IS NOT NULL  THEN
            SQL_STRING := SQL_STRING ||' and trunc(a.last_requested_date) <= to_date(''' ||P_to_date_param || ''',''DD/MM/YYYY'') ';
         END IF;           
      IF P_last_requested_by_param IS NOT NULL  THEN        
              IF P_last_requested_by_param = 'ECM Poltal'  THEN
                    SQL_STRING := SQL_STRING ||' and a.last_requested_by = ''' ||P_worker_id_param || '''';
              ELSE
                    SQL_STRING := SQL_STRING ||' and a.last_requested_by = ''' ||P_last_requested_by_param || '''';
              END IF;
         END IF;             
      IF P_requeset_type_param IS NOT NULL  THEN        
              IF P_requeset_type_param = 'Fax'  THEN
                    SQL_STRING := SQL_STRING ||' and b.billing_tax_fax_id is not null ';
              ELSIF P_requeset_type_param = 'E-Mail'  THEN
                    SQL_STRING := SQL_STRING ||' and b.billing_tax_mail_id is not null ';
              END IF;
         END IF;

 OPEN P_INQUIRY FOR SQL_STRING;
  P_RESULT := 1;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    P_RESULT := 0;
  WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
    P_RESULT := -1;
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    P_RESULT := sqlerrm;

END;

END GET_REPORT;
```

Help me please.
Thanks advance.

Comment: What is your sql query ?

Comment: My sql query : 

"{call PCK_ECM_BILLING.GET_REPORT(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) }";

Answer (score 0):

I have seen "java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index" coming mostly due to two reason:

```
1) Setting column data using setXXXX(int coloumIndex) e.g. setInt(0) setString(0)
2) Getting column data using getXXX(int columnIndex) e.g. getInt(0) getString(0)
```

Most common cause of "java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index" is misconception that column index started with "0" like array or String index but that's not true instead column index starts with "1" so whenever you try to get or Set column data with column index "0" you will get "java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index".

Check if you are assigning `params[i]` to respective indexes. Also, check the `OUT` parameter index which you are passing in the `getObject()` method. It should be 8 or 9.

Comment: I tried  cstmt.getObject(9);     Not error  but return null; //no result.